# 5% Hitleap traffic in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

Some days ago, I published a website so it is not  a that popular. 5-6 days later, I saw that about 5% traffic is from hitleap.com, a traffic exchange service. Since it's not me doing this, I thought what is the guy who added my site in hitleap thinking? Does he want to 'help' me, or why would somebody do this?

Comment: He (or she) probally doesn't care about your site at all :) They might have an automated system, which found your site, that's all. If this becomes a big part of your backlinks, disanvow them (<- plenty of info to find about this).

Answer (score 1):

No, whoever is doing it. He is not trying to help you. It may harm your AdSense account if you're using AdSense on your website.
He is actually trying to get your Adsense account banned. You can contact - [Hitleap Support](https://hitleap.com/support) and ask them to take your website off from their database.

Comment: That could be possible, yeah, I'm actually using AdSense. In the last 30 days, I didn't see any request from HitLeap, but I still contacted the hitleap support to take off my domains. Thank you!